# Can INPUT be less than VDD in TC4420

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver

I'm looking at [TC4420](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/75049/MICROCHIP/TC4420.html).

I want to power it with 10V (because it will be more convenient in my current design), but the signal coming in is 5V.

Looking at the data sheet it says

> Input Voltage .................................. – 5V to V DD  + 0.3V

Which kind of suggests input can differ.

Looking at the block diagram there's also a diode from input to VDD, but I'm not quite sure about what the other things are, and I'm afraid. I really don't want to fry my device.

Well I suppose this is a yes or no question - Is it possible to use a INPUT < VDD voltage safely?

Comment: Did you look at the datasheet's spec for Vih and Vil?

Comment: @Hearth I mean, if the device providing the 5V signal will get fried by powering the driver with 10V and not 5V (same as the other ic)

Comment: It's an input, not an output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; input voltage ranges are normally between VSS < Vin < VDD. Is your concern actually about supply sequencing (the 5V signal could be live before 10V comes up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It says here that anything over 2.4V is considered a logic high.  It doesn't actually say that, the titles and cells used are wrong, but I strongly suspect that that is what they are trying to say.

So a 5V logic signal will be just fine.

Comment: But would that hurt the controller giving off the signal, if it's running at lower than 10V (obviously 5V)?

Comment: the input is shown elswhere in the datasheet as a MOSFET gate, so it should not source significant current, certainly not enough to damage a GPIO.  above it's stated as 10uA -- almost certainly GPIO reotection diodes can handle that no problem.